# AppDelegate can't add subView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, loadview

Since appDelegate does not have a view, just window, its hard to figure out how to load a view from it. My problem has for long been that when didReceiveLocalNotification fires i cant load a new view with that event. I have been working around it til the point that i must do something about it. When i tries to  addSubview, xcode gives me the error:

Receiver tupe 'UIWindow' for instance messages does not declare a method with selector 'addSubView'

for this: (at [self.window addSubView:view];)

```
screwLightBulbViewController *view = [screwLightBulbViewController newMyView];
[self.window addSubView:view];
```

I understand that the appDelegate file does'nt have a addSubview but i want to switch to a particular view when it fires.

I have tried many other ways, like calling a function in screwLightBulbViewController and make a view from that. My function in the viewController now looks like this:

```
+(id)newMyView
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *nibArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    screwLightBulbViewController *me = [nibArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    return me;
}
```

any help in any way would be realy appreciated and thanks for you time. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's `addSubview` not `addSubView:`. `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`.

Adding a view directly as a subview to the window is not usually recommended, so instead you should try and add the view as a subview to the top controller view. If you can spare some time you should look over the [view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503) and [view controller programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1), it will be useful in the future.

Comment: OMG! Well.. Sometimes it's easyer than other times. Thanks!
So i should go for [self.window.view addSubview:view];? Thanks for your links too. :)

Comment: `[self.window addSubview:view]`, `UIWindow` doesn't have any `view` property. You're welcome.

Comment: With your change i corrected the error. My problem is not fully solved, even after reading the content of your links provided. What does '__strong' mean. Should i make it weak? :p

the full warning:
Incompatible pointer types sending 'screwLightBulbViewController' * __strong' to parameter of type 'UIView *'

Comment: So you mean that its not possible to solve my problem? When the didReceiveLocalNotification fires i cant control any view related elements? Do you have any sugestions how to solve my problem?

Comment: I have been playing around with trying this all day. It seems that how much i try, it will never change anything to the current view. The problem is that if i call an other method in another class, the self keyword points to the AppDelegate-file witch does'nt have a view. Therefore i can't interact with any view. Have i got it right? There is no way to make this work. Right?

Comment: You can create some methods/properties in the AppDelegate to return any view (or viewcontroller) you are using in the application, as long as your view(controllers) structure is well defined (e.g if you have a navigation based app, use the `UINavigationBar` methods to get the top view controler; if you have tab based application use the `UITabBarController` methods to get the top  (visible) view controller or any other view controllers you wish to access.